# Get the DPI of Image

Tags: apache-flex

How can I get the DPI of mx.controls.Image?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you draw your bitmap the resolution will be at screen resolution regardless of what the dpi was before it was loaded

Comment: can you say more clearly? Or do you have related link, please show me.